# Xamarin.Auth for authentication via google showing 'signature not valid' and redirecting to same page post authentication

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0, xamarin.android, google-oauth, xamarin.forms

When I am Trying to authenticate via google account within my xamarin application, I am getting the following error in my log (i.e. signature not valid):

```
05-27 14:07:22.624 V/chromium_net(12606): external/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc:514: [0527/140722:INFO:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(514)] ~SSLClientSocketOpenSSL()
05-27 14:07:22.954 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(12606): MyApp.MyApp signature not valid.  Found: 
05-27 14:07:22.954 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(12606): MIIDDTCCAfWgAwIBAgIEB8tB2jANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA3MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UE
05-27 14:07:22.954 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(12606): ChMHQW5kcm9pZDEWMBQGA1UEAxMNQW5kcm9pZCBEZWJ1ZzAeFw0xNjA1MTIxMDMxNTNaFw00NjA1
05-27 14:07:22.954 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(12606): MDUxMDMxNTNaMDcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRAwDgYDVQQKEwdBbmRyb2lkMRYwFAYDVQQDEw1BbmRy
05-27 14:07:22.954 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(12606): b2lkIERlYnVnMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvthA9cxvZnBHqyULJ+XP
05-27 14:07:22.954 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(12606): X0ZF2A3NIe3+gkkM1lbcUqaLvOAVNmQ06Odi2aP25S1eX51jU2lQ90R36/xi0mjjPfZD2JzLOeD+
05-27 14:07:22.954 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(12606): TYzrqguutxLU2BBAduroaAYvYX8Fw3h5J5ySWK2GtvyTcLjMAyslR+8LDZ92FxR0RGNykdDLhMBH
05-27 14:07:22.954 V/GoogleSignatureVerifier(12606): MVb3lyfEuzBLz8TWDR2lhvUzq6DfxcAiEwKw23jxDv7KIjUeGROY2y+G2xnoABGood9m3WX7tant


05-27 14:07:30.344 E/Volley  (12606): [24733] hj.a: Unexpected response code 400 for https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
```

After authentication I am again redirected to the login page instead of profile page.

Can somebody please explain why am I getting this?